# Fatal Python error: PyQt5.QtCore: Unable to embed qt.conf

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been creating a GUI application using PyQt5. This app was perfectly running a few weeks ago but now it shows a Fatal error. I think it is unable to import qt.core. I even tried creating some basic application but still, this error occurs.

**Below is the code for the application:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout,QLabel

#Creating the main window
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTabWidget'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.show()

#Creating tab widgets
class MyTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        #Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(300,200)

        #Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3,"Tab3")

        #Create first tab
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.l = QLabel()
        self.l.setText("This is the first tab")
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.l)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        #Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It is not my application, it is a basic GUI and it shows the same error.
**The error it shows is given below:**

```
Fatal Python error: PyQt5.QtCore: Unable to embed qt.conf
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5' has no attribute '__file__'

Current thread 0x0000000119c675c0 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/major/temp.py", line 2 in <module>
```

Comment: I ran into this issue. Uninstalling and reinstalling PyQt5 and PyQt3D fixed it for me: `pip3 uninstall PyQt5 PyQt3D ; pip3 install -U PyQt3D PyQt5`

Answer (score 0):

I ran this programm, and it work. This error can be if you use python 2 or old pyqt version. It seems you should to update. If it's not so, let me know, please

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using python 3 and pyqt5. It is still not working.